# Contabo Object Storage (S3) with Strapi CMS

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, strapi, object-storage

I'm using Contabo Object Storage (compatible with S3) with Strapi CMS.
For this purpose I'm using: [@strapi/provider-upload-aws-s3](https://market.strapi.io/providers/@strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3)

I've configured it like this (upload and delete works):

```
upload: {
  config: {
    provider: "aws-s3",
    providerOptions: {
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: env("CONTABO_OBJECT_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY"),
        secretAccessKey: env("CONTABO_OBJECT_STORAGE_SECRET_KEY"),
      },
      endpoint: env("CONTABO_OBJECT_STORAGE_ENDPOINT"),
      forcePathStyle: true,
      region: "default",
      params: {
        Bucket: env("CONTABO_OBJECT_STORAGE_BUCKET"),
      },
    },
  },
},
```

The typical S3 url looks like this:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/<MY BUCKET NAME>/filename.extension
```

And this is the format that Strapi expects:

```
https://eu2.contabostorage.com/xxx-bucket/yyy.jpeg
```

However in Contabo Object Storage the public urls look like this:

```
https://eu2.contabostorage.com/zzz:xxx-bucket/yyy.jpeg
```

where **zzz** is the tenantId I think, but I'm not sure

I'm not sure how or where to configure this. I'm hoping someone with more **S3** and **aws-sdk** can help me with this